# Trigger Google Apps Script in Spreedsheet from context menu

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

I have `Google Apps Script` in `Spreedsheet` that works on currently selected row. To run it I have to select this script from script manager. Is it possible to add this script to the context menu or bind to some shourtcut ?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/execution_extensions

Comment: I would be nice to add some menu option in context menu of a cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a menu with button that will run the script that you want using the onOpen function. See the [Apps Script documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_spreadsheet#addMenu).

```
function onOpen() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var entries = [{
    name : "Read Data",
    functionName : "readRows"
  }];
  sheet.addMenu("Script Center Menu", entries);
};
```

You would then have some other function like this.

```
function readRows() {
```

This can execute any function you want, and you can have multiple menu items that do different things.

Note: `onOpen` sometimes takes a while to load, so wait 5 seconds.